# Converting R script to SAS

Tags: r, sas

I want to add noise to a dataset. This is a fairly straightforward procedure in R. I sample from a Laplace distribution and then add/multiply/whatever that vector to the vector I want to add noise to.

The issue is, my colleague is asking for the code in SAS. I have not used SAS since graduate school and my project has been put on hold until I can get my colleague up to speed in SAS.

My code is pretty simple :

```
library ("rmutil")

vector <- c (1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)

vector_prop <- vector/sum(vector)

noise <- rlaplace(9, m=1, s=.1)

new_vector <- vector_prop * noise
```

I am turning my vector I want to add noise to into a proportion, then drawing from a laplace distribution. Finally I multiply those draws with my proportion vector.

Any idea would be helpful as the SAS documentation was difficult to follow. I imagine they feel the same way with R documentation.

Comment: What package is `rlaplace` from?

Comment: library ("rmutil")

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. Why not attempt to translate the code yourself and ask a specific question when you get stuck. Make it clear what the desired output is in SAS so possible solutions can be verified.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a data set called `have` with a variable called `vector_prop` the following code is likely correct. Because of the nature of random numbers and streams you can't replicate that though, don't you end up with a different data set each time?

```
data want;
set have;
call streaminit(24); *fixes random number stream for reproduciblilty;
new_var = vectorProp * rand('laplace', 1, 0.1);
run;
```